# Why use concurrent statements in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl

I am just starting with learning vhdl. 
Consider the code here : - http://esd.cs.ucr.edu/labs/tutorial/jkff.vhd

I can't understand what are concurrent statements and why are they needed here? 
Will it be correct if we modify Q and Qbar directly in process p without using internal signal 'state'? Also why are J,K not in sensitivity list of process p in the snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concurrent statements, as you may know, in a pure functional sense (i.e. not considering hardware implementation) do not incur any delay. So when you write

```
Q <= state;
```

Functionally, `Q` *exactly follows* `state` without any delay.

I am going to guess that the reason an intermediate signal `state` was used, instead of directly assigning `Q` inside the process, is that if you directly assign one of your outputs `Q` in the process, then you cannot "read" the output to derive your `Qbar` signal.

That is, you couldn't do this:

```
Qbar <= not Q;
```

This is because it is not strictly allowable to read an output signal in VHDL. By using "state" you have an internal signal from which you can derive both `Q` and `Qbar`.

An alternative, equivalent implementation to this would be to assign both outputs `Q` and `Qbar` in each of the cases in the state machine, and eliminate the intermediate `state` signal completely. However, this seems a bit more complicated since you will have nearly twice as many lines of code for an equivalent functionality.

---

To answer your second question: J,K are not in the sensitivity list because the process `p` is a synchronous process. You are describing a memory element (JK FlipFlop), which by definition only updates its outputs when `clock` or `reset` change.  Input signals `J` and `K` can change and the process will not update its outputs. Every time there is a clock edge, or `reset` is asserted, the process "wakes up" and evaluates inputs, and determines what the output should be. Even in J,K were included in the sensitivity list, provided your ouputs were only updated on `rising_edge(clock)`, then the overall function would be the same (although your code would be confusing).

Comment: Pedant mode: a concurrent assignment *does* incur a delta-cycle delay. http://www.sigasi.com/content/vhdls-crown-jewel

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason not to have the `Q` and `Qbar` assignments inside the process.  You need to be slightly careful though.

Whenever a signal is assigned to, the value does not update until the simulator moves on to the next "delta-cycle".  This means that within processes, when you assign to a signal, you are axtually only *cheduling* and update and if you read the signal you will get the "old" value.  In order to have the sort of sequential updates you might expect, you use a variable.  So you could model the JKFF like this:

```
architecture behv of JK_FF is
begin
    p : process(clock, reset) is
    variable state : std_logic;
        variable input : std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
    begin
        if (reset = '1') then
            state := '0';
        elsif (rising_edge(clock)) then
            input := J & K;
            case (input) is
                when "11" =>
                    state := not state;
                when "10" =>
                    state := '1';
                when "01" =>
                    state := '0';
                when others =>
                    null;
            end case;
        end if;
        Q  <= state;
        Qbar <= not state;
    end process;
end behv;
```

A synthesis note: the assignments to Q and Qbar occur outside of the `if rising_edge(clk)` so will be interpreted as just like concurrent drivers.